Бесконечный спам пробелов при выводе всех элементов односвязного списка c++
При вызове функции void printToConsole() после добавления минимум одного элемента в список происходит бесконечный спам пробелов в консоль, это как-то связано с утечкой памяти или какая проблема в данной ситуации?
Такая же ситуация была с функцией void printInFile(), но исправив Node *p = first; на Node *p = last; ситуация пофиксилась. Чего не происходит с void printToConsole().
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fstream>

#include "namespace_consts.h"

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    string *persons;
    Node *next;
    Node(string *_persons) : persons(_persons), next(nullptr) {}

    ~Node()
    {
        delete[] persons;
    }
};

struct list
{
    Node *first;
    Node *last;

    list() : first(nullptr), last(nullptr) {}

    ~list()
    {
        Node *p = first;
        while (p)
        {
            Node *next = p->next;
            delete p;
            p = next;
        }
    }

    bool is_empty()
    {
        return first == nullptr;
    }

    void push_back(string *_val)
    {
        Node *p = new Node(_val);
        if (is_empty())
        {
            first = p;
            last = p;
            return;
        }
        last->next = p;
        last = p;
    }

    void printToConsole()
    {
        if (is_empty())
            return;
        Node *p = first;
        while (p)
        {
            for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                cerr << p->persons[i];
            cerr << endl;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }

    void printInFile()
    {
        if (is_empty())
            return;
        Node *p = last;
        ofstream myFile(constText::defaultPath, ios::app);
        while (p)
        {
            if (myFile.is_open())
            {
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    myFile << p->persons[i];
                myFile << endl;
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
};

UPD: Сейчас добавил функцию считывания списка с файла. Если после считывания с файла вывести инфу в консоль, все корректно отображается, получается проблема в функции void push_back(). но вот что именно не так с ней не пойму..
void readFromFile()
{
    ifstream myReadFile(constText::defaultPath);
    string myText;
    while (getline(myReadFile, myText))
    {
        string *data = new string[5];
        uint8_t j = 0;
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < myText.length(); i++)
        {
            if (myText[i] == ';')
                j++;
            j < 4 ? data[j] += myText[i] : data[4] += myText[i];
        }
        pushBack(data);
    }
    myReadFile.close();
}


Проверил работу вашего кода таким образом
int main()
{
    string* a = new string[5] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    string* b = new string[5] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    
    list l;
    l.push_back(a);
    l.push_back(b);
    
    l.printToConsole(); // Output: ABCDE\nABCDE
    
    return 0;
}

В таком варианте все работает, вывод корректен, соответственно метод push_back отрабатывает нормально, для того, чтобы понять в чем ваша проблема приведите вариант использования вашей структуры при которой работа неправильная.
Так же есть некоторые вопросы к вашей реализации:
void printToConsole()
{
  ...
    while (p)
    {
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            cerr << p->persons[i];
        ...
    }
  ...
}

Почему вы распечатываете ровно 5 элементов? Если их окажется меньше 5, то вы столкнетесь с Undefined Behavior, связанным с доступом к памяти, которой вы не владеете (выход за границы массива), если их будет больше, чем 5, то вы распечатаете не все элементы, а только 5 первых.
Решить эту проблему можно несколькими способами:

Если по условию вашей задачи, элементов всегда 5, или не больше 5, то вам стоит использовать std::array<std::string, 5>, в такой реализации вы не рискуете выйти за границы памяти.
Если же количество элементов неизвестно, то можно использовать динамический массив std::vector<std::string>, таким образом вы можете использовать его метод size(), чтобы узнать текущее количество элементов.

cerr << p->persons[i];

Семантически поток std::cerr предназначен для вывода ошибок и не поддерживает буферизацию. Для вывода информационных сообщений лучше использовать поток std::cout.
